# "Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of ' in type cast'"

Tags: flutter

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I sent to another widget The contents of the field's `likeUser` element (currently not yet, but will grow) in the form of a list. And the widget received `likeUser` receives the `likeUser` for namedparameter like this:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: use  list  for likeUser

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to cast chatDocs[index]['likeUser'] to a `List<String>` when it comes as a `String` from Firebase.

You have two choices here:
either changing the way you store data in Firebase, and saving likeUser as a List instead of as a single String; or you change the type for `likeUser` in `BNUE_hosting_form` widget to `String` instead of `List<String>` (which is its current type). Doing this will require you to delete the `as List<String>` when you call `BNUE_hosting_form`.